# Does disabling interrupts in boost disable context switching?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

It is my understanding that the OS kernel is responsible for generating hardware timer interrupts that are used by the scheduler to hand out each thread's timeslice for each core and perform context switching as needed.  I was under the impression that this could only be done from kernel space, and disabling it is usually frowned upon.  However, boost documentation seems to state that it allows the disabling of interrupts:

https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html

Will disabling interrupts with boost effectively pause the scheduler and context switching?  Or, is boost using 'interrupt' to mean only user-space signals or exceptions or something to wake up threads?

Sadly, the term 'interrupt' seems to be rather overloaded, and this makes it easy to get things confused.

Can someone explain what boost is actually doing with its interrupt system here, and how it relates to context switches?

Comment: The Windows API calls this "alertable sleep"; Linux calls it "signals" but sets errno to `EINTR` which is probably where boost got the terminology.  It has nothing to do with real interrupts.

Comment: First question: Do you have a *measurable* performance problem?

Comment: @tadman I am less concerned about performance with this and more concerned about understanding a legacy codebase and avoiding race conditions for which understanding when context switching may occur is important(Some embedded systems manually control the scheduler on embedded platforms so we can make aggressive assumptions about when the code may be interrupted in RTOS designs, I am unsure if that is what boost is doing here)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the simple answer, straight and to the point.  If you respond as an answer I will gladly accept this.

Comment: this is just a way to prevent a `boost::thread` from being interrupted via `thread::interrupt` not more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will disabling interrupts with boost effectively pause the scheduler and context switching?

No.

> Or, is boost using 'interrupt' to mean only user-space signals or
> exceptions or something to wake up threads?

Yes. It only affects thread interruption - which is an optional Boost Thread feature, which is only available when using `boost::thread` and [interruption points from Boost Thread](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption.predefined_interruption_points):

> #### Predefined Interruption Points
>
> The following functions are
> interruption points, which will throw `boost::thread_interrupted` if
> interruption is enabled for the current thread, and interruption is
> requested for the current thread:
>
> - `boost::thread::join()`
> - `boost::thread::timed_join()`
> - `boost::thread::try_join_for(),`
> - `boost::thread::try_join_until(),`
> - `boost::condition_variable::wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable::timed_wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable::wait_for()`
> - `boost::condition_variable::wait_until()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::timed_wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::wait_for()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::wait_until()`
> - `boost::thread::sleep()`
> - `boost::this_thread::sleep_for()`
> - `boost::this_thread::sleep_until()`
> - `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()`

Indeed it implements a style of cooperative interruption using exceptions (`boost::thread_interruption`).